# Three.JS asynchronous processing of geometry

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

I'm working on a web based game that receives terrain-data from a server.

Upon receiving the data, my code constructs a `PlaneGeometry` with 100x100 segments.

When adding the terrain to the scene, the process freezes all of the website for a moment, usually about one second or two.

Is it possible to make this process asynchronous so that the gameplay experience is smoother?

If yes, what can be done?

No code examples needed.

Comment: Try using `PlaneBufferGeometry`, instead.

Comment: Normally you can add a cover and a loader animation, blocking the UI until data has been received and the application is ready. You can also add a `setTmeout` after receiving the data, to give the browser some time to process the rendering. It's pretty common...

Comment: @taseenb that's not acceptable in my application as clients will have to view live data, that's why I'm asking for an `synchronous` approach.

Comment: In that case you have to optimize your process and scene. First, use `PlaneBufferGeometry` as suggested by WestLangley, and second create the geometry BEFORE loading the data and only update the vertices. Second: never add new geometry to the scene: reuse the geometry (and hide it before, when you don't need it, with opacity). It'd be easier if you show some code or a screenshot of what you're trying to do though.

Comment: I see.
How do I re-use geometries? and can I give a re-used geometry an independent rotation, position and material?

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, but it's up to you to figure out how. The reason why it's most likely happening is the transfer to GPU that `THREE.WebGLRenderer` does via `gl.bufferData()` you probably get a lot of geometry at the same time and this process locks the browser. You can try breaking it up when receiving it and adding it to scene/objects in smaller batches.

This happens the first time you call render() while having new geometry not yet encountered by the renderer in the graph.